# Show that $f$ is continuous if it follows the intermediate value property

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

If $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is $1-1$ and has the intermediate-value property -- that is, if $y$ is between $f(u)$ and $f(v)$, there is at least one $x$ between $u$ and $v$ such that $f(x)=y$ -- show that $f$ is continuous.

I have answered this question like so but I feel as if I have missed something or made an assumption that is not true. Could someone look this proof over and tell me if I missed something?

By the definition of this function, the intermediate-value property implies that either $f(u) < y < f(v)$ and $u < x < v$ such that $f(x) = y$, which implies that the function is increasing, or $f(v) < y < f(u)$ and $v < x < u$ such that $f(x) = y$, which implies that $f$ is decreasing. Therefore, $f$ is monotonic. By the definition of the function, $f$ is also $1-1$, and therefore has no jumps or discontinuities. Since $f$ is monotone and $1-1$, it is therefore continuous.

Comment: It seems you didn't use that $f$ is 1-1 for the first part (i.e. to show that $f$ is monotonic. But of course there *are* non-monotonic functions with the intermediate value property (e.g. continuous ones)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: The kicker, here, is that a monotone function can only have jump discontinuities. You should use the fact that $f$ is $1$-to-$1$ and follows IVP (*both of these facts will be needed!*) to show monotonicity, at which point the IVP will rule out jump discontinuities (therefore ruling out *all* discontinuities).

If you want to run an amended proof of monotonicity by me, please feel free to do so, and I'll be glad to critique it (and help you fix it, if necessary).

Comment: Well, that is precisely the path he thinks he took - however the proof of monotonicity is flawed.

Comment: Fair point, Hagen. I was more or less counting on your comment above to alert the OP to that, but I have edited my answer to make that clearer. Thanks!