# Some function with intermediate value property is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Function $f$ is defined from an interval to $\mathbb{R}$, and $f$ takes on each value only finitely many times and satisfies the Intermediate value property, prove $f$ is continuous.

This is a generalization of this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978283/show-that-f-is-continuous-if-it-follows-the-intermediate-value-property?rq=1), but we cannot use the similar method to prove it because this function is not monotonic. In fact, I am not sure whether this proposition is true, however, I cannot find counter example either.

Comment: @Thomas  Misread the question, thanks.  Will delete my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is defined on $[a,b]$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x\in (a,b)$.

Choose $y> x$, such that wlog $f(y)> f(x)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. By the intermediate value property there is $v\in (x,y)$ such that $f(v) = f(x)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Since $f$ takes on each value only finitely often there is a smallest $v>x$ with this property. Applying the intermediate value property again it is easy to see that now $f((x, v]) \subset [-\infty, f(v)]$

If there is $z\in (x, v)$ such that $f(z)< f(x)-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ repeat the argument with $f(x)-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ to show that $f((x, v]) \subset [f(w), f(v)]$ for some $ w$ with $f(w) = f(x)-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$

Now repeat the reasoning for $y<x$ (if $x\neq a$).

It is then easy to see that there is 
$\delta > 0 $ such that $f((x-\delta, x+\delta)) \subset (f(x) -\varepsilon, f(x) +\varepsilon) $